# Regular Expressions ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

```
"(fname:John OR lname:Doe) (male OR female)"

"(fname:John OR address:1200 main str va) (male OR female)"

"(address:1200 main str va OR fname:John ) (male OR female)"

"(fname:John OR address:1200 main str va OR lname:Doe) (male OR female)"
```

Only the first line does not need any change. In the bottom three lines I need to put the address in parenthesis because it has two or more words after the colon.

For example for the second row the modified output should be

```
"(fname:John OR address:(1200 main str va)) (male OR female)"
```

I tried to do it with regex but I am struggling with how to tell regex to look for until you encounter the world OR but if you come across "(" or ")" then stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

```
e.gsub /address:(.*?(?=( *OR| *\))))/, 'address:(\1)'
```

---

Or, with a test case wrapper...

```
[ "(fname:John OR lname:Doe) (male OR female)",
  "(fname:John OR address:1200 main str va) (male OR female)",
  "(address:1200 main str va OR fname:John ) (male OR female)",
  "(fname:John OR address:1200 main str va OR lname:Doe) (male OR female)"
].each do |e|
  puts e.gsub /address:(.*?(?=( *OR| *\))))/, 'address:(\1)'
end
```

Returning...

```
(fname:John OR lname:Doe) (male OR female)
(fname:John OR address:(1200 main str va)) (male OR female)
(address:(1200 main str va) OR fname:John ) (male OR female)
(fname:John OR address:(1200 main str va) OR lname:Doe) (male OR female)
```

Comment: that's awesome. I'll try to understand later how it all works.

Comment: This may help: http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/html/ruby/syntax.html#regexp